# Get the alt for the image on views twig

Tags: views, theming, 8

I've got an image field, in which I'm showing the image using url by setting the relationship for that field on 'Advanced' tab to get the url of the field.

I'm getting the url of the field as

```
{% set image = file_url(fields.uri.content|striptags|trim) %}
    <div class="mob"><img src="{{ image }}" class="testimonial-mob-img" alt="" /></div>
```

I would like to know how to get the alt of the image on `views-view-fields-view-machine-name.html.twig`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution is to add `image` again as a field and Rewrite Results:

[image]

Now in your template:

```
... alt="{{ fields.field_image_1.content|striptags }}" ...
```